# How do you use Observable.create in the FSharp.Control.Reactive library?

Tags: f#, system.reactive

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Observable.create function in the FSharp.Control.Reactive library but seem to be missing something.

The function signature is defined as:

```
((IObserver<'a> -> unit -> unit) -> IObservable<'a>)
```

I've tried a few different ways of creating the observable such as:

```
  Observable.create (fun obs -> fun _ -> obs.OnNext("xxx") )
  |> Observable.subscribe (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

and

```
  Observable.create (fun obs -> obs.OnNext("xxx"); fun _ -> () )
  |> Observable.subscribe (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

Which compiles but doesn't ever execute the OnNext so the printfn statement in the subscribe isn't called.

I can call the Observable.Create method directly from the System.Reactive.Linq namespace as follows:

```
  Observable.Create(fun (obs : IObserver<string>) -> obs.OnNext("www"); Action( fun _ -> () ) )
  |> Observable.subscribe (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

And this will print "www" to the interactive.
Likewise, I can use the Observable.createWithDisposable as follows:

```
Observable.createWithDisposable(fun obs -> obs.OnNext("yyy") ; Disposable.Empty )
|> Observable.subscribe (fun x -> printfn "%A" x)
```

And sending this to interactive prints "yyy"

So it is just the FSharp.Control.Reactive.Observable.create that I am having trouble with.

I've had a look but can't find any examples on how this should be called so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That signature looks quite bizarre to me, but try `fun obs () -> obs.OnNext("xxx")`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this and it compiled but I didn't get the OnNext called.  I've been looking at the implementation of Observable.create and it's defined like this:

    ///  Creates an observable sequence from a specified Subscribe method implementation.
    let create subscribe =
        let subscribe observer = Action (subscribe observer)
        Observable.Create(Func<IObserver<'Result>,Action> subscribe)

Which I don't think is correct.  I might raise an issue on GitHub with the author.

Comment: Agreed, that looks highly suspect to me.

Answer (score 1):

I raised an issue with the developer.  They've removed the Observable.create functions now so you create the observable using the System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Create() methods now.

That makes this question invalid now.

https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Control.Reactive/commit/c8f6d245e75d55b2bd6077c53b311119422c97a1

Answer (score 0):

I once [asked that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23489914/1229323) using c#.

Using F# Control.Reactive would be:

```
        Observable.create(
            fun observer ->                        
                Action (fun () -> 
                    foo.OnBar(
                       fun (args : Args) -> 
                         observer.OnNext(args)            
                         observer.OnCompleted())))
```